# c# Queue values changing inadvertently

Tags: c#, linq

The code below changes the value of the first object placed on the queue.  This is the code to put the first object on the queue:

```
//put the initial Ma value on the movingAverageQueue
movingAverageQueue.Enqueue(previousMa)
```

This line of code changes the first object above I already placed on the queue

```
previousMa.Close = previousMa.Close - sub/period;
```

What am I missing in my logic for this code?

here is the full code:

```
public class MA
{
    public static Queue<DateClose> MAMethod(Queue<DateClose> queue,
        Queue<DateClose> firstMASample, int period)
    {

        Queue<DateClose> sample = new Queue<DateClose>(firstMASample.ToArray());
        Queue<DateClose> movingAverageQueue = new Queue<DateClose>(queue.Count() + 1);
        // get the last item or initial MA value from the queue
        DateClose previousMa = firstMASample.LastOrDefault();
        sample = new Queue<DateClose>(firstMASample.Take(firstMASample.Count - 1));
        DateClose mA = null;
        decimal sub = 0;
        DateClose add = null;
        //put the initial Ma value on the movingAverageQueue
        movingAverageQueue.Enqueue(previousMa);
        foreach (DateClose d in queue.ToList())

        {
            mA = sample.Dequeue();
            sub = mA.Close;
            previousMa.Close = previousMa.Close - sub/period;

            add = d;
            sample.Enqueue(d);
            previousMa.Close = previousMa.Close + add.Close/period;
            previousMa.Date = add.Date;
            movingAverageQueue.Enqueue(previousMa);
            queue.Dequeue();
        }

        return movingAverageQueue;
    }
}
```

The DateClose class is:

```
public class DateClose
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Close { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: "What am I missing in my logic for this code?" How about you tell us what is happening/not happening? And what you expected to happen/not happen?

Comment: You assign `previousMa` in one place. It is assigned to be a reference to the last item in `firstMaSample` if there is one. You are adding this same reference over and over again to `movingAverageQueue`. You will end up with a queue where every item in the queue is the same item. Is it possible that you need to discover the difference between value types and reference types? Or have you forgotten to assign `previousMa` again within the loop?

Comment: Richardissimo, I realized i should use a deque.  I found an amazing one here, https://github.com/StephenCleary/Deque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, object references are passed by value, and so you are enqueing a reference to that object. The reference in the queue is still pointing to the same memory location, and so when you alter the object you will see those changes when you dequeue that object reference.

[Jon Skeet article on C# parameter passing](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html#value)

Comment: *object references are passed by value*... Perhaps not the best way of phrasing an explanation of "passing by reference" vs "passing by value".

Comment: I know it sounds a bit strange at first, but that's distinct from pass by reference. The article I linked has a boxed off aside that clarifies this.