# Access and copy values in objects instead of accessing the reference to the object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am attempting to populate a moving average queue but I am getting the same date and close for all of the objects in the moving average queue.  I am stuck as how to not get the reference pointing to the same object instead of getting the current value in the object and placing that value on the queue.

```
public class MA
{
    public static Queue<DateClose> MAMethod(Queue<DateClose> queue,
        Deque<DateClose> firstMASample, int period)
    {
        Deque<DateClose> sample = new Deque<DateClose>(firstMASample.ToArray());
        Queue<DateClose> movingAverageQueue = new Queue<DateClose>(queue.Count() + 1);
        // get the last item or initial MA value from the queue
        DateClose mA = sample.RemoveFromBack();
        DateClose dateClose = null;
        decimal sub = 0;
        DateClose add = null;
        //put the initial Ma value on the movingAverageQueue
        movingAverageQueue.Enqueue(mA);
        foreach (DateClose d in queue.ToList())
        {
            dateClose = sample.RemoveFromFront();
            sub = dateClose.Close;
            // subtract previous closing from new current MA
            mA.Close = mA.Close - sub/period;
            // add the new closing to new current MA
            add = d;
            sample.AddToBack(d);
            mA.Close = mA.Close + add.Close/period;
            mA.Date = add.Date;
            movingAverageQueue.Enqueue(mA);
            queue.Dequeue();
        }

        return movingAverageQueue;
    }
}
```

movingAverageQueue has all the same Date and Close values.

Comment: What is the significance of `DateClose mA = sample.RemoveFromBack();`?  Why are you reusing this object? If keeping some values from `DateClose` is necessary, you'll have to implement a [clone method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icloneable?view=netframework-4.7.2), or make `DateClose` an immutable struct.

Comment: Is this really any different than **[yesterday's episode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53382229/1070452)**?

Comment: Disaffected, yesterday's question taught me I was using references instead of values.  Today I am asking how can I access the values since I obviously know how to access them by reference.  I am teaching myself C#.

Comment: John, the immutable structure sounds like the way to go.  I will try it.  I appreciate your response.

Comment: But is there a specific reason for reusing the value returned by `sample.RemoveFromBack()`? Note that by providing all the information you can, we can probably give you better advice - my advice may be bad _in your situation_  because I don't have all the facts available to me.

Comment: Yes and without an [MCVE] it is hard to tell, but I would bet you have the same problem as yesterday.  In your loop, you are adding the same `mA` object over and over (even if one property is modified as you go).

Comment: Disaffected, in my initial post, I mention I am getting the same mA object over and over again.  I know why I am getting it.  My questions is how to get the value instead of the reference, over and over again.

Comment: @Jam66125 Please explain what youa re doing so that we can provide you with a proper answer. Do you need to retain some values from `sample.RemoveFromBack()`?

Comment: You have a Queue, a Deque and a movingAverageQueue with data moving back and forth between them...seems thats where your thing went off the rails.  As best I can tell, you need a collection for the data.  The moving average is a simple calculation you can (and ought to) perform on the fly.

Comment: John, I am using a deque I found today because in the SMA function, I want the date and close values for the period and the SMA.  I can only return on type from the function so I used a deque to put the SMA value on the end and take it off in the MA function as the first value in the moving averages queue.

Comment: Can you add the `DateClose` definition to your question?

Comment: namespace myBackEnd.Models
{
    public class DateClose
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public decimal Close { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: In how far is your question even remotely related to [tag:asp.net-core]???

Comment: Tseng, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/tutorial-csharp-aspnet-core?view=vs-2017

Answer (score 0):

I solved this of accessing by value instead of by reference with creating two new objects in the for loop,  It works!

```
        public static Deque<DateClose> MAMethod(Queue<DateClose> queue,
        Deque<DateClose> firstMASample, int period)
    {
        Deque<DateClose> sample = new Deque<DateClose>(firstMASample.ToArray());
        Deque<DateClose> movingAverageQueue = new Deque<DateClose>(queue.Count() + 1);
        // get the last item or initial MA value from the queue
        DateClose mA = sample.RemoveFromBack();
        //DateClose dateClose = null;
        decimal sub = 0;
        DateClose add = null;
        //put the initial Ma value on the movingAverageQueue
        movingAverageQueue.AddToBack(mA);
        foreach (DateClose d in queue.ToList())
        {
            // create a new object for add subtraction moving averages           
            DateClose dateClose = new DateClose(sample.RemoveFromFront());
            sub = dateClose.Close;
            // create a new object to place the new moving average on the queue
            DateClose mAQueueValue = new DateClose(movingAverageQueue.Last());
            // subtract previous closing from new current MA

            mAQueueValue.Close = mAQueueValue.Close - sub/period;
            // add the new closing to new current MA
            add = d;
            sample.AddToBack(d);
            mAQueueValue.Close = mAQueueValue.Close + add.Close/period;
            mAQueueValue.Date = add.Date;
            movingAverageQueue.AddToBack(mAQueueValue);
            queue.Dequeue();
        }

        return movingAverageQueue;
    }
```